# how to glue C++ with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++

What libraries are commonly used to glue C++ & javascript ? I'm interested in the glue working both ways, that is constructing C++ objects & calling their methods from Javascript and the other way round.

E.g. for glue-ing C++ & python boost::python is commonly used, what would be the equivalent for C++ & Javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

Different Javascript engines exposes it's internals via a different API. I've never seen a shared wrapper that does the job.

Comment: I'm really not familiar with Javascript, my experience is mostly in C++ and some Python. Can you recommend wrappers for the most popular Javascript engines, e.g. which would be a popular wrapper for the V8 engine?

Comment: Google's documentation would be a good place to start, https://developers.google.com/v8/embed

Comment: Thanks for this, out of curiosity how would you rank the top 2-3 javascript engines in terms of adoption. Is v8 the most popular one?

Comment: I don't know. I've used v8 and Apple's JavascriptCore framework. Obviously the latter locks you in to Apple operating systems.